# Database for Real Time Queries/Push Notifications

Tags: ios, sql, database, parsing, nosql

I am looking to build an iOS app and website that work *'together'*.

What the plan is for each:

- On the iOS side, it will be pushing information to the server in the form of a post.  The users will then be able to vote up and down on the posts as well; which also implies they will be able to see the other users information (in real time).
- The website will be viewing this information in real time and using the posts.  If a post gets enough down votes the server should tell the website and apps to remove it.

I have experience with SQL. Although SQL does not seem to be the appropriate server choice - for what I want to do - given my experience with it.  (I could definitely be wrong.)

I would like to host the information myself, however have heard that Parse is good about holding information for iOS apps.  I just don't know whether it gives you enough freedom to work with websites as well.

TL;DR: What kind of database/datastore should I use for a real time queries that allows for push notifications?

All suggestions are welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using FireBase

[firebase.google.com](http://firebase.google.com)

[Documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD9be74fDQAhUkTY8KHaiDA6wQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2F&usg=AFQjCNEM5-_5Zujozyi5wjBGlkKkKUDtCQ&sig2=HEe8PHl_u2Dn0xF2Ix0Cuw)